# Is there a way to load data into cassandra from HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hdfs

I am looking for an option to load my data from HDFS to cassandra. Is there any way to achieve this requirement?

The scenarios is

i) I have created a datamodel in cassandra similar to the data available in HDFS

ii) Now i want to export my hdfs data to the created cassandra data model.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kalai

Comment: Yes, there is a 'backdoor' way of pushing it in without making a query for each record.

Comment: @samthebest Can You please let me know how to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

"Builds SSTables and uploads them
Uses a custom partitioner to mirror the topology in the reduce step"

https://github.com/spotify/hdfs2cass

Comment: Thank you. I will check this and get back to you. Thanks again